# How to run build/deploy only on *.rdl files

Tags: vba, reporting-services, command-line, rdl

I'm running the below build command from `CMD` (runs on `windows` slave from `jenkins`):

```
 bat "devenv.com MyProject.sln /Build Release"
```

My output to `bin\Release` are `*.rdl` files + `*.obj files` + `*.rds files`

After that, I'm running the below deploy command:

```
  bat ' rs.exe -i pipeline/ssrs/Upload_Multiple_RDL_files.rss -s "{My report server}" -v FILE_NAME="pipeline/ssrs/ConfigurationFile.txt" '
```

and here I get error once it reached non `rdl` files:

```
 The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services
```

Is there a way to avoid it? for example, run build and see only the `*.rdl` files in `bin\Release` or modify `Upload_Multiple_RDL_files.rss` `VB` script which I took from [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/925355a3-baec-44ef-a3ee-b5b2023a6527/need-help-uploading-multiple-reports-using-ssrsmigrationrss?forum=sqlreportingservices) to run only on `*.rdl` files?

`Upload_Multiple_RDL_files.rss` content:

```
'Script Starting Point
' Script to deploy report to report server
' EXECUTE VIA COMMAND LINE

DIM definition As [Byte]() = Nothing
DIM warnings As Warning() = Nothing

Public Sub Main()

' Variable Declaration
        Dim TextLine As String = ""
        Dim LocalDir As String = ""
        Dim ServerDir As String = ""
        Dim definition As [Byte]() = Nothing
        'Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing

' Reading Configuration Text file and assigning the values to variables
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
                Dim parts As String() = TextLine.Split(New Char() {","c})
                'TextLine & objReader.ReadLine() '& vbNewLine
                LocalDir = parts(0)
                ServerDir = parts(1)

                Dim path As String = LocalDir
                Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(path)
                Dim fileFullPath As String = ""
                For Each fileFullPath In fileEntries


' Deploying the Reports
                    Try
                        Dim stream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(fileFullPath)
                        Dim NameWithExt As String = fileFullPath.Replace(path, "")
                        Dim NameOnly As String = NameWithExt.Replace(".rdl", "")
                        definition = New [Byte](stream.Length-1) {}
                        stream.Read(definition, 0, CInt(stream.Length))

      warnings = rs.CreateReport(NameOnly, ServerDir, True, definition, Nothing)

      If Not (warnings Is Nothing) Then
        DIM warning As Warning
        For Each warning In warnings
        Console.WriteLine(warning.Message)
        Next warning
      Else
       Console.WriteLine("Report: {0} PUBLISHED!", NameOnly)
      End If

     Catch e As IOException
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
     End Try
    Next fileFullPath
   Loop
         Else

            Dim MsgBox as String = "File Does Not Exist"

        End If
End Sub

'End of the Script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not `VB` expert, but the below worked for me after adding this `if` condition:

`If NameWithExt Like "*rdl*" Then`

full script:

```
'Script Starting Point
' Script to deploy report to report server
' EXECUTE VIA COMMAND LINE

DIM definition As [Byte]() = Nothing
DIM warnings As Warning() = Nothing

Public Sub Main()

' Variable Declaration
        Dim TextLine As String = ""
        Dim LocalDir As String = ""
        Dim ServerDir As String = ""
        Dim definition As [Byte]() = Nothing
        'Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing

' Reading Configuration Text file and assigning the values to variables
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FILE_NAME)
            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
                Dim parts As String() = TextLine.Split(New Char() {","c})
                'TextLine & objReader.ReadLine() '& vbNewLine
                LocalDir = parts(0)
                ServerDir = parts(1)

                Dim path As String = LocalDir
                Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(path)
                Dim fileFullPath As String = ""
                For Each fileFullPath In fileEntries


' Deploying the Reports
                    Try
                        Dim stream As FileStream = File.OpenRead(fileFullPath)
                        Dim NameWithExt As String = fileFullPath.Replace(path, "")
                        Dim NameOnly As String = NameWithExt.Replace(".rdl", "")
                        definition = New [Byte](stream.Length-1) {}
                        stream.Read(definition, 0, CInt(stream.Length))
      
                        If NameWithExt Like "*rdl*" Then
                            warnings = rs.CreateReport(NameOnly, ServerDir, True, definition, Nothing)
                            Console.WriteLine("Report: {0} PUBLISHED!", NameOnly)
                        End If

                    Catch e As IOException
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
                    End Try
                Next fileFullPath
                Loop
        Else
            Dim MsgBox as String = "File Does Not Exist"
        End If
End Sub

'End of the Script
```